# consuming wcf The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme Anonymous

Tags: wcf, .net-core, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, wcf-security

we are consuming Third party WCF services, Application was working fine, we were about to go live and client implemented ssl certificate.

Details about the SSL change EMAIL RECEIVED FROM HOST

> During the announced changes we performed an SSL certificate change. The issuing Certification Authority (CA) for the *.*.* wildcard
>   certificate is now DigiCert Global Root G2 .
>
> It is necessary to install the DigiCert Global Root G2 certificate
>   only into your corresponding application and **not** the *.*.*
>   certificate at all
>
> You can find the new CA root certificate which is required to perform
>   an SSL handshake on the DigiCert website
>
> The certificate chain for the client certificate looks like this
>
> 1.Root CA certificate: 
>   2.Intermediate CA certificate:
>   3.Client certificate: USER1001.p12
>
> The issuing Certificate Authority (CA) for the client certificate
>   chain is the XYZABC Systems CA. If the Root CA and Intermediate CA
>   certificates are not integrated into your trust store, then the client
>   certificate on your system will show an error that the issuer of the
>   certificate cannot be found. However, your client certificate will
>   still be recognized as valid by the host system and its webserver,
>   even without integrating the Root CA and Intermediate CA certificates
>   in your truststore.

I have downloaded all the certificate and installed in my Local Machine.
here attached my code which was working earlier and started giving error after sll implementation.

```
  System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();

        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;

        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

        //Creates ServiceClient, attach transport-binding, Endpoint and the loaded certificate
        Services service = new Services (binding, new EndpointAddress(EndPoint));

         X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2( ApplicationSetting.CertificateFilePath,  ApplicationSetting.PrivateKeyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet );

        service.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;
        service.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());
        Response response;
        try
        {
             response = service.Callservice(g110Request);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
```

when we approach the client again they replied with this.

> A 403 error indicates a missing certificate. Please check if you have
>   set up the certificate settings within your environment. If you use
>   SoapUI, go to preferences -> SSL Settings and check the KeyStore
>   directory towards your certificate.